# Neo4j: MissingIndexException on a Node

Tags: scala, neo4j, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j

I'm trying to setup a skeleton of Spring-Data-Neo4j project in Scala.
When I run the JUnit test, and I get a MissingIndexException, I really don't have any clue why. I previously ran the same test successfully using the same configuration (and dependencies) in pure Java instead of scala entities/test.

Any help would do.

The (scala) persistent entity:

```
@NodeEntity
class User extends Identifiable {

    def this(email: String = null, name: String = null) = {
        this()
        this.email = email
        this.name = name
    }

    @Indexed
    var name: String = _

    @Indexed (unique = true)
    var email: String = _

    @Fetch
    @RelatedTo(`type` = "IS_A", direction = Direction.BOTH)
    var agent: Agent = new Agent
}
```

Here is the (still java) repository interface:

```
public interface UserRepository extends GraphRepository<User> {
    @Query("start n=node:User(email={0}) return count(*)")
    int count(String email);

    User findByEmail(String email);
}
```

The JUnit test I run:

```
@Test
@Transactional
def testCountEmails = {
    assertEquals(0, userRepository.count("mail"))
    userRepository.save(new User(email = "mail"))
    assertEquals(1, userRepository.count("mail"))
}
```

An excerpt of the log:

```
[main] DEBUG org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.query.CypherQueryEngineImpl - Executing cypher query: MATCH (ref:ReferenceNode {name:{name}}) RETURN ref params {name=root}
[main] DEBUG org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.query.CypherQueryEngineImpl - Executing cypher query: match (n) with n limit 1 set n:`SDN_LABEL_STRATEGY` remove n:`SDN_LABEL_STRATEGY` return count(*) params {}
[main] DEBUG org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.schema.SchemaIndexProvider - CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (n:`User`) ASSERT n.`email` IS UNIQUE
[main] DEBUG org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.query.CypherQueryEngineImpl - Executing cypher query: CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (n:`User`) ASSERT n.`email` IS UNIQUE params {}
[main] DEBUG org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.schema.SchemaIndexProvider - CREATE INDEX ON :`User`(`name`)
[main] DEBUG org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.query.CypherQueryEngineImpl - Executing cypher query: CREATE INDEX ON :`User`(`name`) params {}
```

And the error I get:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: Error executing statement start n=node:User(email={0}) return count(*); nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: Error executing statement start n=node:User(email={0}) return count(*); nested exception is org.neo4j.cypher.MissingIndexException: Index `User` does not exist
```

Comment: Can you confirm which version(s) of SDN and Neo4j you were using both the Scala project and the pure Java project?

Comment: Yes, this is neo4j 2.0.1 and spring-data-neo4j 3.0.0-RELEASE. The dependencies are the same for the pure java version (except for the scala libraries of course, and one extra joda-convert dependency). I can't attach the dependency tree here unfortunately cause it exceeds the allowed characters count in a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you're likely using Cypher 2.0, and looking at your query, you don't have a MATCH--just a START and a RETURN.  So, first off, I'm not even sure that's legal, but you say it ran before...I've never seen that. :)

That said, I'm pretty sure that the START clause makes use of legacy indices, and it looks like you're attempting to treat :User as a label (which is new to Neo4j 2.x).  So, when SDN creates the schema indices (with "name" and "email" as your keys), the START statement is attempting to access a legacy index for "User" which does not exist.

Maybe try this as a query and let us know how it goes:

```
MATCH (n:User {email: <whatever>}) RETURN count(*);
```

Also make sure that your parameterization is being taken care of.

(If I'm off on any of this, someone please feel free to correct me.)

HTH

Comment: BTW I realize that all that was switched (allegedly) was the use of Scala instead of Java, so I'm basing my answer based on what I see. Past that, I can't think of anything off the top of my head that would cause Scala to behave differently.  Perhaps Michael Hunger might shed some light on it otherwise.

Comment: You were right, thank you. That is indeed specified in the up-to-date neo4j reference doc (http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/query-start.html).

As for where I found the start-return syntax, I couldn't point to the exact doc I have in mind, but if you look at the Quick start guide of SDN, you'll find this kind of syntax in the examples (http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-neo4j/#quick-start).

I still have the previous working version in a git branch, so I'm sure I can reproduce it working, but anyways... it's solved! :) Thanks

Comment: Glad it worked. I remember looking at the intro docs for SDN but that was awhile ago. :) SDN is ultra-cool though.  Good luck!

Comment: Fyi, the Spring Data Reference is full of start queries (mystery resolved): http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-neo4j/docs/3.0.2.RELEASE/reference/html/programming-model.html#reference_programming-model_repositories

Comment: Indeed it is. Holdover from older docs, but still applicable. I hope they update it if they ever get rid of START all together.